# Problems saving correlation plot: dimension

Tags: r, r-corrplot

In the past I've saved `ggplot2` but the correlation plot when saved loses its dimensions and I cannot understand why.

Let the context be this code:

```
cor.matrix <- structure(c(1, 0.492955134006126, 0.506712693586509, 0.492955134006126, 1, 0.467841635024973, 0.506712693586509, 0.467841635024973, 1), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("(0)0003", "(0)0005", "(0)0006"), c("(0)0003", "(0)0005","(0)0006")))

par(oma=c(6,3,4,3), cex.axis = 0.9, mar = c(3,5,3,2), mgp = c(1,0.4,0))
cairo_pdf("Test.pdf", 10,12)

corrplot::corrplot(cor.matrix,method = "color", order = "alphabet", cl.pos = "b", tl.pos = "n")

title(main="Correlation Matrix Between Bus Lines",outer=T, cex.main = 2, font.main = 3 , family = "Georgia", adj = 0.5)  
title( sub = paste0("Alphabet Order"), outer = T, cex.sub = 1.5)

dev.off()
```

The output is the following plot which I had to take a screen shot because the default format is *.pdf*.

The problem emerges because even thought I've tried lots of variates in the `par` parameters, `height` and `width` parameters of the `cairo_pdf` function the output doesn't change.

Could you please help me understand what do I have to do so the tittle + subtitle fit in the image?

[image]

Comment: Try adding `line = -.25` in the first `title()` command. Change `-.25` to what works.

Comment: It did solve the problem!